# Discrete analogues of known spaces, their relations and properties.

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $M(X)$ be the space of all finite Borel $\mathbb{R}$-valued measures on $X$, where $X$ is metric space, and $m=M(\mathbb{N})$.

It is known that
$$L^p[a;b]\subset L^q[a;b]\ \text{with}\ 1\leq q\leq p\leq \infty,$$
$$BV[a;b],C[a;b]\subset L^1[a;b],$$
$$C[a;b]\cap BV[a;b]\neq C[a;b], BV[a;b],$$
$$\text{there are natural isomorphism}\ BV[a;b]\,\widetilde{\to}\,M[a;b]\ \text{and inclusion}\ L^1[a;b]\hookrightarrow M[a;b],\ \text{etc.}$$

But for discrete analogues of these spaces we have (inclusions may not be continuous)
$$\ell^q\subset \ell^p\ \text{with}\ 1\leq q\leq p\leq \infty,$$
$$\ell^1\subset bv\subset c,$$
$$\ell^1\neq bv\neq c,$$
$$\text{there are a natural isomorphisms}\ m\,\widetilde{\to}\,bv\,\widetilde{\to}\,\ell^1.$$
where
$$bv=\big\{(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\, \big|\, \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty|x_{n+1}-x_n|<\infty\big\},$$
$$c=\big\{(x_n)\, \big|\, \exists\, \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n\in\mathbb{R}\big\}.$$

So, if anyone knows examples in the spirit of the above, please share.

**Remark 1.** I know that it depends on definitions and that my question is rather inaccurate. However, I am interested in what can happen if, when moving to the discrete case, one of the main ideas underlying the definition of a space is preserved.

**Remark 2.** If we assume all sequences $x=(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ are "smooth" and assume $x^\prime_k=(x_{k+1}-x_{k-1})/2$ then it is easy to define discrete analogues $d$ and $s$ of space of test functions $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ and Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}_1$ respectively (the topology on them can be set following classical reasoning).

I have described the distributions on these spaces: if $\lambda\in d^\prime$ ($\lambda \in s^\prime$) then there is sequence $(\lambda_k)$ such that
$$\lambda (x)=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty \lambda_k x_k\ \text{(and}\ |\lambda_k|\leq C|k|^N\ \text{with some}\ C=C(\lambda)>0,\, N=N(\lambda)\in\mathbb{N} \text{).}$$

And for each sequence $(\lambda_k)$ functional $\lambda(x)=\sum \lambda_kx_k$ belongs to $d^\prime$ (if $|\lambda_k|\leq C|k|^N$ then $\lambda\in s^\prime$).

Comment: What is preserved here? The inclusions are reversed at the contrary, right?

Comment: @LL 3.14, yes, the inclusions are reversed at the contrary. However, there are other features (for example, the isomorphism of the space of integrable functions and the space of functions of bounded variation). And the ideas of "integrability", "continuity" and "bounded variation" are preserved.

Comment: Perhaps you could be interested by norms defined in terms of singular values of operators https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.03013